# POST data into JSON array with jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I dont even know where is  wrong code in my ajax, i learn from the internet but still i cant POST data.
My html code :

```
<h3>Input new data</h3>
<form name="contact">
    <input type="text" placeholder="id berita" id="idberita" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="title berita" id="titleberita" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="content berita" id="contentberita" />
    <input id="create_at" type="datetime-local">
    <button type="submit" id="add-data">add</button>
</form>
```

This is my ajax code :

```
$('#add-data').on('click', function() {
    var order = {
        id        : $idberita.val(),
        title     : $titleberita.val(),
        content   : $contentberita.val(),
        create_at : $create_at.val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type   : 'POST',
        url    : 'json/student.json',
        data   : order,
        success: function(newContent) {
            $orders.append('<li>dataid: '+newData.id+', title:'+newData.title+', content:'+newData.content+', create_at: '+newData.create_at+'</li>');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('error saving data');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the page reloads because form submits?

Comment: Use newContent instead of newData! after success

Comment: the page reloads,data cant input and i look at the console not show anything.. @guradio

Comment: what's your eerror?

Comment: because the page already reloaded

Comment: when i try input the data and the console show this "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)"  @masterpreenz

Comment: Isn't url `json/student.json` supposed to be a GET request?

Comment: and now my page not reloads, but in the console show "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)" @guradio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, submitting a form refreshes the page. Jquery's [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)  is always passed as the first argument of your event handler, so use it to prevent this behavior:

```
       $('#add-data').on('click', function(event) {
             event.preventDefault();

              var order = {
                id: $('#idberita').val(),
                title: $('#titleberita').val(),
                content: $('#contentberita').val(),
                create_at: $('#create_at').val(),
            };


            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'json/student.json',
                data: order,
                success: function(newContent) {     
                    $orders.append('<li>dataid: '+newContent.id+', title:'+newContent.title+', content:'+newData.content+', create_at: '+newData.create_at+'</li>');
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('error saving data');
                }
            });

        });
```

Comment: i tried you suggestion ang then page not reloads, but when input the data and i look at the console showing "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)"

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: You may also want to add  `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json", cache: false` options to your ajax call.

Comment: i know, i cant input from the local json file

Answer (score 0):

use `.serialize()` it will collecting all data input element within form into a set of array, you dont need to define by one by

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: $("#formid").serialize(),
  url : "your/post/url",
  success: function(callback){
     // success handler
  },
  error: function(){
    // error handler
  }
})
```